# What's the point of making an intersection with the unknown in the TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

In ts-toolbelt sources I saw making intersection with unknown.

```
export type ComputeRaw<A extends any> = A extends Function
  ? A
  : { [K in keyof A]: A[K] } & unknown; // intersection with unknown
```

I wonder why to do so, because it makes no sense? It is said in [TS docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type): "In an intersection everything absorbs unknown".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really doesn't make sense. It has no effect here, at least from what I tested.